# Need to implement 3D touch on App icon similar to recent contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, 3dtouch

I tried to implement 3d touch feature for my app similar to Apple's contact app to show some favorite icon with image title and subtitle as shown in below image
[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH8Yf.jpg)
But what I developed it's looked like this

[What I can Develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhRvK.png)
is there any way I can develop this? or apple not allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a Today Widget to show that view.

Comment: can you provide little guide How I can show today widget on 3d touch?

Comment: It is automatically displayed, see WhatsApp.